# Javascript Regex Form Validation Booking Reference

Tags: regex

I'm doing some coding as part of college work, my current module is about Regex in JavaScript forms.

I've been using lots of different online websites and tutorials but can't get my head around how to set it to validate the following.

It is a JavaScript form which is validating a field. I need the form to reject any submission that isn't as follows:

- Begins with either ACFT, GTHA or LKAM
- the word must then be followed by a hyphen,
- then follow the number 1 or 2
- and finally 4 random numbers

So far I've managed to validate it for 4 letters a hyphen and 5 numbers by using this

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{4}\-\d{5}$/
```

But obviously this isn't near what I need hah

Wondering if anybody could give me guidance on this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
^(ACFT|GTHA|LKAM)-[12]\d{4}$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Vg8xMu/2)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ACFT                     'ACFT'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GTHA                     'GTHA'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LKAM                     'LKAM'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [12]                     any character of: '1', '2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: @James Please kindly [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).